# How to get mean from a dictionary of dataframe across each key per row

Tags: pandas, excel, mean

How can I calculate the mean across all the dataframes in a dictionary, where each dataframe represents an experiment ("experiment1" to "experiment5"), and obtain a  3x1 mean vector for each column (V1 and V2) in the dataframes?

```
dict_df[key]

    V1  V2  
0   5   10  
1   3   10  
2   4   16
```

I tried to do it with a for loop which calculates:

```
m1V1 = (dict_df["experiment1"]["V1"][0] + ... + dict_df["experiment5"]["V1"][0])/5
m2V1 = (dict_df["experiment1"]["V1"][1] + ... + dict_df["experiment5"]["V1"][1])/5
m3V1 = (dict_df["experiment1"]["V1"][2] + ... + dict_df["experiment5"]["V2"][2])/5

m1V2 = (dict_df["experiment1"]["V2"][0] + ... + dict_df["experiment5"]["V2"][0])/5
m2V2 = (dict_df["experiment1"]["V2"][1] + ... + dict_df["experiment5"]["V2"][1])/5
m3V2 = (dict_df["experiment1"]["V2"][2] + ... + dict_df["experiment5"]["V2"][2])/5
```

I'm having trouble accessing the necessary values.

I also tried:

```
out=pd.concat(df_dict.values()).mean(level=0)
```

But I get the error "'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable".

What is a more efficient way to calculate the means for each column (V1 and V2) across multiple experiments stored, where each mean is obtained by summing the corresponding values across experiments and dividing by 5? I'm having trouble accessing the necessary values.

I created the dictonary by:

```
dfs = {}

for (i, experiment) in enumerate(all_experiments):
    df = pd.read_fwf(experiment)
    df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns=['V1', 'V2'])
    df_['V1'] = torch.tensor(df['V1'].values, dtype=torch.float32)
    df_['V2'] = torch.tensor(-df['V2'].values, dtype=torch.float32)
 
    dfs[i] = df_

df_dict = pd.concat(dfs, sort=False)
```

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example of the input dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html) after [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
pd.concat(dict_df).groupby(level=1).mean()

# or
# pd.concat(dict_df, axis=1).groupby(level=1, axis=1).mean()
```

Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
dict_df = {f'experiment{i+1}': pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 2)),
                                            columns=['V1', 'V2'])
           for i in range(5)}
out = pd.concat(dict_df).groupby(level=1).mean()
```

Output:

```
    V1   V2
0  5.6  3.4
1  2.2  5.0
2  6.8  6.2
```

[numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) alternative:

If the DataFrames are already aligned (same indexes and columns), you could also use [`numpy.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

```
out = pd.DataFrame(np.mean(list(dict_df.values()), axis=0),
                   columns=['V1', 'V2'])
```

Comment: I get the error: "first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"". I uploaded the way I created the dictonary. Is it wrong?

Comment: @user362981 the code you provided is unfortunately not reproducible, but it looks like `dict_df` is a DataFrame, not a dictionary so just skip the `concat` step.